# Upgrading Firestore v1beta1, to v1? (using ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY in filters)

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm currently trying to make a connection from my Firestore Database to Mailchimp (using Zapier) and got this error:

```
Error code 400: [{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "'ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY' filters are not supported in Firestore v1beta1, please upgrade to v1.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } ]
```

I can't seem to find any information on how to do this however.

Is there any other way to get this done? This is the query:

```
{
"orderBy": [
  {
   "field": {
"fieldPath":"timestamp"
},
"direction": "DESCENDING"
  }
],
  "where": {
    "compositeFilter": {
      "op": "AND",
      "filters": [{
        "fieldFilter": {
          "field": {
            "fieldPath": "selectedItems"
          },
          "op": "ARRAY_CONTAINS",
          "value": {
            "stringValue": "Wind"
          }
        }
        
      },
      {"compositeFilter": {
        "op": "AND",
        "filters": [{
          "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
              "fieldPath": "tags"
            },
            "op": "ARRAY_CONTAINS_ANY",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "poland"
            }
          }
        }
     
      
      ]
      }}
   
    
    ]
    }
  }
```

}

I need to be able to have multiple values under tags but not to have them all have to be in the array.

thank you :)

Comment: Did you try to update to `v1`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't know how to do that, could you explain?

Comment: @OlaMichalska, have you tried this [step to get the latest version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_latest_version_of_the_sdk)?